# Prove that $\eta (1/2) \gt \frac{\sqrt 2 \pi^2}{48}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, zeta-functions

> Prove that $\eta (1/2) \gt \frac{\sqrt 2 \pi^2}{48}$

I am out of any good ideas, but the $\pi^2$ suggests some comparison with $\zeta(2)$.

Here is a bad try:

$$\eta (1/2) \gt 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$$

Now it just remains to show that $\frac{\sqrt 2 \pi^2}{48} \lt 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} + \frac{1}{\sqrt 3}$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If we are talking about the [Dirichlet eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) then try this trick:
$$\eta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^s}=\frac 1{1^s}-\frac1{2^s}+\cdots$$
so:
$$\eta(s)-1=-\frac1{2^s}+\frac1{3^s}-\cdots$$
$$2^s\left[\eta(s)-1\right]=-1+\frac{2^s}{3^s}-\cdots=-\eta(s)+2^s(\zeta(s)-1)$$

(Sorry I'm trying to do this in my head) anyway you get the expression:
$$\eta(s)=\left(1-2^{1-s}\right)\zeta(s)$$
so if we extend the eta function through an extension of the zeta function we can define its value in terms of $\zeta(1/2)$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly that helps?